# Is this line grammatically correct ? " and is mostly targeted to web developers."

Tags: verbs, tenses, verb-agreement

I found one [article](https://medium.com/canal-tech/how-video-streaming-works-on-the-web-an-introduction-7919739f7e1) online which says :

> this article is an introduction to video streaming in JavaScript and
>   **is** mostly **targeted** to web developers.

The thing I am not able to understand in this line is **is** and **targeted**. Is it correct usage ? or it should have been :

> and is mostly targeting ...

Comment: The sentence is fine as it is, but if you wanted to use the active voice, there would be no need for the progressive. The article mostly targets web developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence is okay, except I would say 'at web developers'. I expect your confusion is the suspicion you are using a present tense 'is' with the past tense 'targeted'. 'Targeted' is an adjective, not a verb, in your sentence. It is called the past participle of the verb 'to target'. You can always use the past and present participles of verbs, the -ed and -ing forms, as adjectives. That is the point of grammar you probably need to research.